# Linear programming with matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, ipython, linear-programming

I have a matrix as following:

```
lift
Out[147]: 
array([[188, 149, 147, 129, 104],
       [104, 168, 197, 114, 119],
       [134, 157, 152, 153, 103],
       [126, 176, 174, 126, 151],
       [137, 146, 168, 183, 121]], dtype=int64)
```

I'm trying to minimize it, subjected to the condition that the row summation should be less than the following matrix:

```
Constt
Out[148]: 
array([[12000],
       [18000],
       [18000],
       [12000],
       [12000]])
```

I've used the following code:

```
res = linprog(lift, A_ub=lift, b_ub=Constt, bounds=list(zip(VminA, VmaxA)), options={"disp": True})
```

VminA and VmaxA are (5 X 5) matrices consisting of the bounds. I'm not getting the solution. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-149-cd1e2b9696bc>", line 1, in <module>
    res = linprog(lift, A_ub=lift, b_ub=Constt, bounds=list(zip(VminA, VmaxA)), options={"disp": True})



 File "C:\Users\hp1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linprog.py", line 993, in linprog
    bounds=bounds, callback=callback, **options)

  File "C:\Users\hp1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_linprog.py", line 579, in _linprog_simplex
    L[i] = bounds[i][0] if bounds[i][0] is not None else -np.inf

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Can somebody help me here? Also please tell me how should I add another constraint regarding column summation?

Comment: Your arrays look like numpy. Are they numpy array normal array or numpy array?

Comment: Hi, the 'lift' array is from a certain df.values and the Constt array is numpy.

Comment: I think `c` should be 1 x 5 (your first argument). `A_ub` and `b_ub` are in correct dimensions, it seems.

Comment: What is the number of variables? Is it `5` or `5 x 5 = 25`? As @titipata pointed out, the size of the first argument `c` should be the same as the number of the variables. Moreover check the size of `bounds`. It should be a sequence of tuples and the size is the number of variables.

Comment: yeah there are 25 variables (5 X 5)

Comment: @titpata, I get this error:ValueError: Invalid input for linprog with method = 'simplex'.  Number of columns in A_ub must be equal to the size of c

Comment: If you got 25 vars, the shape of A_ub is wrong (and one could discuss the type; but i'm assuming scipy will just eat the ints). This also fits the error. Just see every row in A_eq as constraint like ```row * x <= b_ub``` (i left out transposes and co.; math works out). Obviously the number of columns need to be the same as elements in c, so 25.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't follow, what should I do?

Comment: Just get familiar with the standard-form of LPs (lots of resources). scipy's API is somewhat less restricted, but it still assumes you understand this form (algebraics). The last error you described it just an effect of the assumption: width of constraint-matrix (size of 2nd dim of 2d-array) = len of objective-vector (size of 1d-array). If you expect someone to show working code, you will have to describe your problem more precise, maybe with a simplified example